# Line breaks in the description - MS Teams App Studio

Tags: json, botframework, microsoft-teams, microsoft-appstudio

In the MS Teams App Studio, in Manifest Editor.

I have a bilingual description for our app and want to separate them some way.

[Example snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/59aWV.png)

How can I insert a break line? Is it even possible.

```
I have tried \n , \\n , &, and br tag
```

Comment: you CAN have multi-line strings in JSON, which is what an app manifest is saved as, however, it would appear that however Teams is rendering that JSON into the 'description' box, it's not reading those linebreaks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of putting bilingual one after other you could show one based on  the client language settings. Please take a look at [Localization file JSON schema](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/resources/schema/localization-schema) to support multiple languages.